# success url to the current url

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm using django class based view and forms. I want the view to stay on the same page after a new message has been submitted. The url is like

```
localhost:8000/chat/messages/username/
```

where 'username' is the username of the user to which the message is being sent

```
class ThreadView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'thread.html'
    form_class = ComposeForm

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Thread.objects.by_user(self.request.user)

    def get_object(self):
        other_username  = self.kwargs.get("username")
        obj, created    = Thread.objects.get_or_new(self.request.user, other_username)
        if obj == None:
            raise Http404
        return obj

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        thread = self.get_object()
        user = self.request.user
        message = form.cleaned_data.get("message")
        ChatMessage.objects.create(user=user, thread=thread, message=message)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

urls.py:

```
app_name = 'chat'

urlpatterns = [
    path("", InboxView.as_view()),
    url(r'^messages/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)', ThreadView.as_view(), name="chaturl"),
]
```

If I give `success_url='./'` it's going to `locahost:8000/chat/messages/`, which results in a 404 error.

Comment: You don't need to check `request.user.is_authenticated` in `post` since you are using `LoginRequiredMixin`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could override the `get_success_url` method and reverse the url:

```
from django.urls import reverse

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('chat:chaturl', kwargs={'username': self.kwargs['username']})
```

Or if you want the path that the request was submitted from, you could use [`request.path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path).

```
from django.urls import reverse

def get_success_url(self):
    return self.request.path
```

Comment: As a method in your view.

Comment: i actually want the username to be username of the user whom im sending the message to and not request.user.... I did it like

Comment: def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('chaturl', self.kwargs.get("username"))   And i get ModuleNot found error

Comment: *I get ModuleNot found error* - that's not enough information for me to be able to help you. Edit your question and show the code and the full traceback of the error.

Comment: No module named '<username>'

Comment: My `reverse()` was incorrect. See the updated answer